# Lemons from my garden are really hard. Is there a solution to this?

Tags: lemons

Lemons from my garden are really hard. Is there a solution to this?
Here some details. 
I'm in a tropical country (Sri Lanka)
here its a sandy soil. I dont use any commercial fertilizers on them.
My lemon plant is 1 year old. nearly 1m high fully grown. Can't squeeze it for juicing. but its so much yellow and ripe. Why does it happen? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with sandy soil is that while it allows natural rainfall and irrigation to percolate down to the roots the soil cannot hold on to the moisture long enough for the tree to benefit fully from it. If you examine the leaves of citrus you will find that they are often coated with a waxy shiny surface which helps reduce trainspiration but the fruits are a lot softer and liable to be too dry and with some varieties even crack open as they dry out. You may be able to find a local supply of organic material such as sugar cane bagasse as a top dressing on the soil. This would help keep moisture in the soil longer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this method and let you know for sure!